# List the full path of all files in folders and subfolder older than X days and save result in a text file LINUX

Tags: list, file, path

I am knew in Shell programmming and I have been fighting  to script the following requitemnt.

1- List all files older than X days in a folder and its subfolders
2- List each file's name and full path
3- Write the result a text file.

Thanks for your help.

Script is:

`MY_DIR1="/media/nssvolumes/TEST/ORIGIN`
`find $MY_DIR1 -mindepth 0 -maxdepth 3 -mtime +1 -type f`
`find $MY_DIR1 | sed 's:""$DIR"":: > toto.txt`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Which part are you having trouble with? If you want to avoid the sed, you can do this:

```
cd $MY_DIR1 && find . -mindepth 0 -maxdepth 3 -mtime +1 -type f > toto.txt
```

in a script. If you want to preserve the current directory, put parentheses around the whole thing to do it in a subshell.